# Uncaught ReferenceError: settings is not defined prettyPhoto

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

using prettyPhoto (3.1.5) and jQuery (jquery-1.9.1.js). I am getting the following error when I close and the popup and try to reopen it.

```
 .bind('click',function(){
                if(!settings.modal) $.prettyPhoto.close();

            });
```

(Error Here: `Uncaught ReferenceError: settings is not defined`)

Comment: Did you include jQuery library before prettyphoto library?

Comment: Why are you only showing such a small part of your code?

Comment: Macsupport,here on this section i got error

Comment: Well the variable "settings" isn't in the context for this particular line. We'll have to all your code to know why but you can probably solve it yourself if you try and move where "settings" is defined.